# HTML break tag confuses order of items processed by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The following code to switch images works as expected... until, for formatting reasons, a different HTML tag is introduced to the flow of the controls.  By inserting a simple break tag (asterisked below), the block that follows has its logic shifting by one, i.e. clicking on

- `pict/8/tiny` will reveal `pict/4/large`
- `pict/4/tiny` will reveal `pict/5/large`
- `pict/5/tiny` will reveal `pict/6/large`
- `pict/6/tiny` will reveal a blank

A break tag is allowed within a paragraph tag, but why is it confusing the  spans for the javascript purpose? And how can this be fixed?

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#image-flip_controls").on('click', 'span', function() {
        $("#image-flip img").removeClass("opaque");
    
        var newImage = $(this).index();
    
        $("#image-flip img").eq(newImage).addClass("opaque");
    
        $("#image-flip_controls span").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='image-flip_controls'>
      <span class="selected"><img src="/pict/1/tiny_27122_20170321160746452.jpg" /></span> 
      <span><img src="/pict/2/tiny_LI_P_20150215_059.jpg" /></span>
      <span><img src="/pict/3/tiny_LI_P_20150215_056.jpg" /></span>
      <span><img src="/pict/7/tiny_41513_20180525135457797.jpg" /></span>

    **<br />**

      <span><img src="/pict/8/tiny_27130_20170321160804655.jpg" /></span>
      <span><img src="/pict/4/tiny_LI_P_20140901_016.jpg" /></span>
      <span><img src="/pict/5/tiny_LI_P_20120130_005.jpg" /></span>
      <span><img src="/pict/6/tiny_EN_P_20140615_033.jpg" /></span>
    </p>

    <div class='row'>
      <div id='image-flip' class='shadow'>
        <img class="opaque" src="/pict/1/large_27122_20170321160746452.jpg" />
        <img src="/pict/2/large_LI_P_20150215_059.jpg" />
        <img src="/pict/3/large_LI_P_20150215_056.jpg" />
        <img src="/pict/7/large_41513_20180525135457797.jpg" />
        <img src="/pict/8/large_27130_20170321160804655.jpg" />
        <img src="/pict/4/large_LI_P_20140901_016.jpg" />
        <img src="/pict/5/large_LI_P_20120130_005.jpg" />
        <img src="/pict/6/large_EN_P_20140615_033.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Note that the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index of an element is its position within the parent element.

Given `<div> <img> <img> </div>`:

- The first image is the first element in the div
- The second image is the second element in the div

Given `<div> <img> <br> <img> </div>`:

- The first image is the first element in the div
- The second image is the third element in the div

You seem to expect the `<br>` element to be ignored. It won't be. It is an element.

---

Use [`.index( selector )`](https://api.jquery.com/index/#index-selector) to get the index within a jQuery collection instead.